# PDO code not working on 000webhost but works on localhost

Tags: pdo

So I'm having an issue which I cannot figure out, for my order form, once it's filled out and paid for, the customer will get email confirmation and then the order is created in my sql table. What I've done works fine on my localhost but not when I'm using 000Webhost.

This is the page that I am having issues with:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['date'])) {
$date = $_SESSION['date'];
}

$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$number = $_SESSION['number'];
$address = $_SESSION['address'];
$town =  $_SESSION['town'];
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];
$county = $_SESSION['county'];
$post = $_SESSION['post'];



if (isset($_SESSION['collectFrom'])) {
$collection = $_SESSION['collectFrom'];
}


$price = $_SESSION['price'];
if (isset($_SESSION['delivName'])) {
$delivName = $_SESSION['delivName'];
}

echo $delivName;
if (isset($_SESSION['delivEmail'])) {
$delivEmail = $_SESSION['delivEmail'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['delivNumber'])) {
$delivNumber = $_SESSION['delivNumber'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['delivAddress'])) {
$delivAddress = $_SESSION['delivAddress'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['delivTown'])) {
$delivTown = $_SESSION['delivTown'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['delivPostcode'])) {
$delivPostcode = $_SESSION['delivPostcode'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['delivCounty'])) {
$delivCounty = $_SESSION['delivCounty'];
}

$stdQuant = $_SESSION['stdButtery'];

if ($stdQuant == ""){
    $stdQuant = 0;
}

$vegQuant = $_SESSION['vegButtery'];

if ($vegQuant == ""){
    $vegQuant = 0;
}

$banffQuant = $_SESSION['banffButtery'];

if ($banffQuant == ""){
    $banffQuant = 0;
}

$specialQuant = $_SESSION['specialButtery'];

if ($specialQuant == ""){
    $specialQuant = 0;
}





        if (isset($_SESSION['date'])) {


        try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO buttery_orders (name,email,number,address,town,postcode,county,stdButteries,veggieButteries,banffButteries,specialButteries,
                post,collection,date_required,price) VALUES (:name, :email, :number, :address, :town, :postcode, :county,
                :stdButteries, :veggieButteries, :banffButteries, :specialButteries, :post, :collection, :date_required, :price)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':date_required' => $date,
                    ':name' => $name,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':number' => $number,
                    ':address' => $address,
                    ':town' => $town,
                    ':postcode' => $postcode,
                    ':county' => $county,
                    ':stdButteries' => $stdQuant,
                    ':veggieButteries' => $vegQuant,
                    ':banffButteries' => $banffQuant,
                    ':specialButteries' => $specialQuant,
                    ':post' => $post,
                    ':collection' => $collection,
                    ':date_required' => $date,
                    ':price' => $price

                ));
                header("Location: confirmation.php");
                exit;


            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        } else if (isset($_SESSION['delivName'])) {

        try {

                //insert into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO buttery_orders (name,email,number,address,town,postcode,county,stdButteries,veggieButteries,banffButteries,specialButteries,
                post,delivName,delivEmail,delivNumber,delivAddress,delivTown,delivPostcode,delivCounty,price) VALUES (:name, :email, :number, :address, :town, :postcode, :county,
                :stdButteries, :veggieButteries, :banffButteries, :specialButteries, :post, :delivName, :delivEmail, :delivNumber, :delivAddress, :delivTown, 
                :delivPostcode, :delivCounty, :price)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':name' => $name,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':number' => $number,
                    ':address' => $address,
                    ':town' => $town,
                    ':postcode' => $postcode,
                    ':county' => $county,
                    ':stdButteries' => $stdQuant,
                    ':veggieButteries' => $vegQuant,
                    ':banffButteries' => $banffQuant,
                    ':specialButteries' => $specialQuant,
                    ':post' => $post,
                    ':delivName' => $delivName,
                    ':delivEmail' => $delivEmail,
                    ':delivNumber' => $delivNumber,
                    ':delivAddress' => $delivAddress,
                    ':delivTown' => $delivTown,
                    ':delivPostcode' => $delivPostcode,
                    ':delivCounty' => $delivCounty,
                    ':price' => $price

                ));
                header("Location: confirmation.php");
                exit;


            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

        }


?>
```

and this is my sql table:

[image]

Like I said this works on local host but not with 000webhost, I am getting the error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'delivName' doesn't have a default value

and if I remove delivName, it says the same for delivEmail and so on. So what's the issue here? And why is it fine with localhost but not here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'delivName' doesn't have a default value

This means three conditions are true:

1. You're inserting a record into that table without specifying a value for that column.
2. That column does not allow `null`.
3. That column has no default value.

Looking at the screen shot of your table definition, conditions 2 and 3 are indeed true.  And looking at your `INSERT` statement, so is condition 1:

```
INSERT INTO buttery_orders (name,email,number,address,town,postcode,county,stdButteries,veggieButteries,banffButteries,specialButteries,
            post,collection,date_required,price) VALUES (:name, :email, :number, :address, :town, :postcode, :county,
            :stdButteries, :veggieButteries, :banffButteries, :specialButteries, :post, :collection, :date_required, :price)
```

The error is telling you exactly the problem.  You need to do at least one of the following:

1. Specify a value for that column when inserting a record.
2. Allow `null` values in that column in the table definition.
3. Specify a default value for that column in the table definition.

   > And why is it fine with localhost but not here?

Presumably something is different in that scenario.  Maybe the table definition is different, maybe you've made a mistake in your debugging, etc.  But the error you're seeing here makes complete sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll have a look at the sql table for my localhost and see if I can find any differences I might have missed. The pdo script I've written is the same as the localhost one as it was just uploaded to 000webhost

Comment: Works now that I allow null values, checked both sql tables and my 000Webhost one did seem to be exactly the same as my localhost one which is what I'm finding really strange. No matter though, thanks again for the help